# Opening an embedded PPT file makes refreshing the formulas in Excel

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I have some data in my Excel with linked formulas in it. I have set the formula calculation to manual. If I make any changes to the linked cells nothing will happen to the formula cells as the calculation is set to manual.
But when I am opening any embedded Excel file in PPT it is refreshing the excel file formulas automatically.
If I check the calculation is still manual. Why it is updating or refreshing the excel file formulas after opening of PPT embedded Excel file.
Note: There is no connection between the embedded file and the excel formula file. You can open any embedded file it will refresh the formulas.

I tried using VBA also but same issue coming